# Why am I being prompted to select an answer for a Community Wiki question?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, community-wiki

I have two question posts that were converted to Community Wiki, but the "newbie alert" for answer acceptance still shows up when I see them in my profile.  Can this be fixed?

[Non-OEM Biometric Software?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/1674/non-oem-biometric-software)

[Which Instant Messaging services use or allow secure protocols, and what do those protocols cover?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/1634/which-instant-messaging-services-use-or-allow-secure-protocols-and-what-do-those)

Answer (score 2):

Community wiki does not preclude accepting an answer.

The reminder goes away after a fixed # of days.

Comment: ...and yet, they don't count against your acceptance rate?